# Alternating series test $\sum_{n\ge2}\ln\left(1+(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> ***My question is about one of the alternating test conditions.***
>
> Let this example to illustrate my comments
>
> $\sum_{n\ge2} u_n$ with $u_n=\ln\left(1+(-1)^n\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)$

**May I use the taylor expansion to do the test??**

For instance $\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}+o(n^{-2})$ so $u_n=(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+o(n^{-2})\right)$

Let $v_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $w_n=o(n^{-2})$

**Should I test  $(v_n+w_n)$ and how to show $w_n$ is strictly decreasing for all $n$?**

Comment: "how to show $w_n$ is strictly decreasing for all $n$?" What for? One does not want to apply the alternating series theorem to $\sum w_n$...

Comment: @Did Ok, thanks, we apply the absolute convergence to $\sum w_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

thus

$$u_n=(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}+(-1)^no\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)=v_n+w_n$$

$w_n$ is **absolutely convergent**.

Comment: $\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)$ big O is better I think

Comment: @Stu ops...of course you are right! just a typo, I prefer little-o notation!